# PHP - LDAP Authentication and Search

Tags: php, authentication, active-directory, ldap

I am using an Online LDAP Test Server here: http://www.forumsys.com/tutorials/integration-how-to/ldap/online-ldap-test-server/ to test some basic LDAP code.

I need to authenticate a user and retrieve some user information.

If I understand the information about the test server correctly I should be able to bind with users that belong to respective groups. With the code 'AS IS' below I can bind to un-commented $dn, but if I use any other $dn to authenticate, the bind fails.

**What am I not understanding?**

For example, tesla should belong to 'ou=scientists,dc=example,dc=com' but I am unable to authenticate tesla on that DN and subsequently I can't search for related information.

```
    $dn = 'dc=example,dc=com';
    // $dn = 'ou=mathematicians,dc=example,dc=com';
    // $dn = 'ou=scientists,dc=example,dc=com';

    $username   = 'tesla';
    $password   = 'password';
    $filter     = "(uid=" . $username . ")";

    $ldapDN     = 'uid=' . $username . ',' . $dn;

    $ldapCONN   = ldap_connect("ldap.forumsys.com") or die("Could not connect to LDAP server.");

    if ($ldapCONN)
    {
        ldap_set_option($ldapCONN, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);

        $ldapBIND = @ldap_bind($ldapCONN, $ldapDN, $password);

        if ( $ldapBIND )
        {

            $result = ldap_search($ldapCONN, $dn, $filter) or die ("Error: ".ldap_error($ldapCONN));

            $data   = ldap_get_entries($ldapCONN, $result);

            echo '<pre>';
                print_r($data);
            echo '</pre>';

        } 
        else
        {
            echo "LDAP bind failed...";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using LDAP, it is important to visualize how the database is organized.

Basically, **all** users are in the main folder. Use this folder to authenticate your user with, otherwise it will not work.
In this case the main folder where all users are in, is `dc=example,dc=com`. However, most LDAP servers use a main folder like `cn=users,dc=example,dc=com`.

Why are they using folders at all then? Well, that is to make it easier to categorize and search with a filter. For example, if you want to only show the names of scientists, you add the group Scientists to your search filter like `$filter = "(ou=Scientists)"`. A filter for both groups would look like this: `$filter = "(&(ou=Scientists)(ou=Mathematicians)"`. Now the server will take a look into this folder/these folders, and display just these members.

Hope this helps, for gaining further insight in how the server is organized, I can recommend installing Apache Directory Studio. It is free to download from [their site](https://directory.apache.org/), helped me a lot!

Comment: Actually, your answer clarified the use of filter for me. I see now that I misunderstood it. I will try this out as soon as I'm back at the computer. One question. Can I create a filter that would contain both scientists and mathematicians? I'll definitely look at Apache Directory Studio. Thanks!

Comment: Sure, no problem! I added it to my answer above. Hope this helps you. Additionally, recently I started writing an LDAP page on Stack Overflow Documentation, see http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ldap/5576/getting-started-with-ldap#t=201703250629537435003. Maybe it will help you further, I also wrote some examples of filters there.

Comment: That looks good. Very helpful, thank you. My goal on the actual project is to authenticate and then filter by group and username. I know what I need to find so I need it to be as efficient as possible. I didn't realize filters are so flexible. That alone was great help :) I accepted tour answer.

Comment: Nice! Good luck with your project!